# Are these two parametric lines the same?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> True or false? We have that $A=B$ where
>
> $A=\left\{(-3,14)+(2,6) \cdot x \mid x \in
> \mathbb{R}\right\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$ and
>   $B=\left\{(-7,2)+(\frac{5}{6},\frac{15}{6})\cdot x \mid x\in
> \mathbb{R}\right\}\subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$

How would you check that? I tried for A:

$\begin{pmatrix}
-3\\ 
14
\end{pmatrix}+x\begin{pmatrix}
2\\ 
6
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ where I get two different solutions $x=\frac{3}{2}$ and $x=-\frac{7}{3}$, thus not solvable.

and B:

$\begin{pmatrix}
-7\\ 
2
\end{pmatrix}+x\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{5}{6}\\ 
\frac{15}{6}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}$ where I get that $x=\frac{42}{5}$ and $x=\frac{4}{5}$

Which means the statement is false?

Comment: No, that just means neither of the pass through the origin. You need to try to equate them and see if they are equal for all x.

Comment: @ZiadFakhoury: Not really "equal for all $x$", because if they are the same line, they still don't have the same parametrization. For example, setting $x=0$ gives us $(-3,14)$ in $A$ and $(-7,2)$ in $B$, which are not the same -- but $(-7,2)$ is in fact in $A$, just then for $x=-2$.

Answer (score 2):

They are different lines. In fact, if you replace $x$ by $y=\frac{12}{5}x$ in the definition of $B$ you get

$$B =\{(-7,2)+ (2,6)\cdot y \ | \ y \in \mathbb R\},$$

so that $A$ and $B$ are parallel lines with empty intersection.